# How do i make the animate function to be called on the next element of same class one by one not all at the same time

Tags: jquery

Here's what I am trying to do I am making some animated number counters and what I would like to do is to make them start on the next element only after its done with 1st so that they all don't fire up just like that at the same time.
Here's the code
HTML
    <div class="count">
        <div class="num-label">
            <span class="number">20</span>%
        </div> of something
    </div>

```
&lt;div class="count"&gt;
    &lt;div class="num-label"&gt;
        &lt;span class="number"&gt;80&lt;/span&gt;%
    &lt;/div&gt; of something else
&lt;/div&gt;
```

Css

```
.count{
    width:100%;
    font-size:3rem;
    text-align:center;
}
.num-label {
    font-size:7rem;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initcounter();
    function initcounter(){
        $('.number').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var count = $this.text();
            jQuery({ counter: 0 }).animate({ counter: $this.text()}, {
               duration: 7000,
               step: function () {
                   $this.text(Math.ceil(this.counter));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get sequenced animation, you can try to use [`$.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects. As `animate` method return `deferred` it can be chained. Like so:

```
function animateBlock($el) {
  return $el.animate({
    marginTop: 100
  }, 300)
}
// Alert when animation is done
$.when(animateBlock($('#block'))).then(function() {
  alert('done!')
})
```

### Sequenced animation

```js
function animateBlock($el) {
  return $el.animate({
    marginTop: 100
  }, 300)
}

var $els = $('.block');
var defer = $.Deferred().resolve();

$els.each(function(i) {
  var $el = $(this);
  // Add next deffered to chain, it will be invoked when previous is completed
  defer = defer.then(function() {
    return animateBlock($el)
  })
})
```

```css
.block {
  background: gold;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```